# Looking for online space to collaborate but NOT open source

Tags: open-source, vbscript

I have an applicaion, that can best be described 'loosly' as a scripting application, primarly designed for part time developers, engineers and sciences types with a VB.NET background (can theoretically do C#).

This has been a long three year hobby and I am about 95% complete.  I am planning to make the applicaiton freely available for most (if not all) uses, but I do not want to open source it (at least right now).

I was looking for an online place to post and collaborate with some folks for feedback, to get some testing done and finalize the application (my wife wants me to be DONE with it).  My searches online have revealed many spaces, but all seem to be open-source spaces that require release of the source code, or just aplace to post 'free' completed software.  I am looking for the collaboration part.

Can anyone point me to a such a space that does not require providing the open source code (if it even exits)?

Comment: Will those doing the testing and providing feedback have access to the source?  Or, just you?  I'm asking, because it is often the case in a closed-source project where those testing will have access to the source, but the public will not.

Comment: Right now, just me with access to the source.  But I really do need developer types to test becuse it has an API and uses .NET for scripting.  I would provide source for sample code.

Comment: I use BitBucket.  You can use it for closed-source projects.  It has a basic feature set, but may work for you.

Comment: I created a BitBucket account.  Looks like it might work.  Many of the sites require you to choose an open source license before you even create a space.  BitBucket does not.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a BitBucket account. Looks like it might work. Many of the sites require you to choose an open source license before you even create a space. BitBucket does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use most of the collaboration places without actually uploading any source to the repository.

I've seen a bunch of project on Google Code Hosting that have no source (usually its then on  GitHub) and just use the Google Hosting for bug-tracking and collaboration.

Comment: Unfortunately, per Goodgle FAQ - "Can I use Google Code to host projects that aren't open source? Nope. Open source projects only."  I'll keep them in mind though, I suppose the worse they could do is kick me off.